# How to check if currentUser matches a users field within an entry?

Tags: entries, users

I've already found the entry, and the 'users' field can contain multiple users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this on the Slack chat and Brad Bell kindly came to the rescue.

---

```
{% set match = false %}

{% for user in entry.users %}
    {% if user.username == currentUser.username %}
        {% set match = true %}
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}

{% if match %}
    User matches!
{% endif %}
```